# Minimum volume bounding tetrahedron to a convex hull

Tags: math, geometry

I would like to know about possible algorithms for finding a minimal volume bounding ( circumscribing ) tetrahedron to a given convex hull. I just basically want to approximate an arbitrary 3D shape, initially defined as a cloud of points, as a tetrahedral shape.

Comment: I don't think you'll get an easy answer for this, but if you're willing to go for an approximate one, how about starting with 4 faces of the convex hull to define an initial tetrahedron, and then iteratively improve, possibly with simulated annealing?

Comment: What kind of shape do you want to bound? Is it a point cloud? A polytope? Is if convex? How is it stored?

Comment: The four-faces idea should work since in fact there is a theorem which states that each face of the tetrahedron must be tangent to the hull

Comment: In lieu of Armando, search for "Minimum Oriented Bounding Box". Check out wiki for starts. It will point you to Joseph O'Rourke paper. It is actually a hard problem with slow algorithmic solution, but it will give you idea of how to approach this.

Answer (score -1):

You can try a marching cube with tetrahedons.